# Angular Material mat-radio-buttons within a mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a dynamic Angular Material `mat-table` with a radio button column. How can I get the radio buttons to all be within the same `mat-radio-group`? The following template produces one group per row, so the radio buttons are unrelated to each other and multiple can be checked at once.

```
<table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8 table">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="selectRadio">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="row.selected" (change)="radioSelected(row)">
        <mat-radio-button [value]="true"></mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columnSchema" [matColumnDef]="column.column">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{column.title}}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      {{element[column.column]}}
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used `[(ngModel)]="row.selected"`. Here `row.selected` is different for all the rows.
If you want to single radio for your entire table then take one variable in your TS. And use that variable in `[(ngModel)]`. And you can use row as a value of radio so you will get selected row in your newly defined variable.

For example.

HTML

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedRow" (change)="radioSelected()">
    <mat-radio-button [value]="row"></mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

TS

```
selectedRow;

radioSelected() {
  console.log(selectedRow);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Insert in You mat-cell only mat-radio-button like in example, without mat-radio-group

```
 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
     <mat-radio-button style="margin-bottom: 12px;" [value]="true" (change)="radioSelected($event, row)"></mat-radio-button>
 </mat-cell>
```

and for get informatin from selected row use this method

```
radioSelected = (event: MatRadioChange, row: **object in table**) => {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(row);
  }
```

i am testing this and its work perfect. Selecting radio i every row deselect in another.